# Find extrema of function in region specified by polygon

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I am finding the extrema of a function with the code below.

The window over which I am finding the extrema is specified by 'xm', at the very beginning. The window is a simple square, from -xm to +xm in both x and y.

**I would like this region to be speficied by a polygon, like an octagon or a pentagon.**

- I have looked at [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html), but it does not seem compatible with the function that I use to do the extremisation (end of question), since it is using the window size without doing any plot.
- The option that I am currently trying but that has not produced results yet is specifying `Region = Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 3}]`

to then limit the extremisation to the Region with:

```
 ... ∈ Region
```

I am starting with a rectangle to be simple, than I guess I'd have to define an octagon / pentagon with lines and vertices. I don't really have an idea of the correct syntax this should be used in so  I am trying out different combinations.

Any pointers, help?

--

CODE:

```
α = 100; 
beams = 8;
angle = (2 π)/beams;
xm = {6,10};
plotting = True;


k0 = 2 π;
k0 = {k0, 0};
k = Table[FullSimplify[RotationMatrix[n*angle]. k0], {n, 0, beams - 1}];


epol[θ_, ϕ_] := {Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ], 
   Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
θ = ConstantArray[0, beams];
ϕ = ConstantArray[0, beams];


Intensity = ConstantArray[1, beams]; (* Intensity of each beam *)
δ = ConstantArray[0, beams]; (* Phase of each beam *)
Efield[x_, y_] := 
 Table[Sqrt[Intensity[[n]]]*Exp[I k[[n]].{x, y} - I δ[[n]]]*
   epol[θ[[n]], ϕ[[n]]], {n, 1, beams}]


Efieldtot[x_, y_] := Sum[Efield[x, y][[n]], {n, 1, beams}]
Potential[x_, 
  y_] := α*
    Sum[Conjugate[Efieldtot[x, y][[n]]]*Efieldtot[x, y][[n]], {n, 1, 3}] // 
   ComplexExpand // Simplify

usefulstuff = 
  Table[FindExtrema[Potential, xm[[n]], 250], {n, 1, Length[xm]}];
```

where the Function to extremise is:

```
FindExtrema[potential_, windowsize_, points_] := 
 Module[ {dx, dy, hl, x, y, hes, crit, mnp, mxp, sdp, mini, maxi, 
   sadl}, 
  {dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[potential[x, y], {{x, y}}]; 
  hes[x_, y_] = D[potential[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];
  crit = Cases[
    Normal[ContourPlot[
      dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -windowsize/2, windowsize/
       2}, {y, -(windowsize/2), windowsize/2}, PlotPoints -> points, 
      ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
    Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
       FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
         dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
          y0}}]), ∞];
  hl = hes @@@ crit;
  mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl; 
  mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl); 
  sdp = Thread[mnp ⊽ mxp];
  mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
  maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
  sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];
  {mini, potential @@@ mini, hes @@@ mini, maxi, potential @@@ maxi, 
   hes @@@ maxi}
  ]
```

--

Comment: Are you sure that this is really a minimal working example representing your problem? In other words, wouldn't you be able to generate a simpler example that still showcases your problem, but doesn't require us to understand and wade through quite as much code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as "how to convert a rectangle into a proper `Region`?"

```
rec = Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 3}];
Head @ rec
```

> Rectangle

Create a region with

```
reg = BoundaryMesh @ DiscretizeRegion @ rec
```

[image]

```
Head @ reg
```

> BoundaryMeshRegion

`RegionPlot` shows that the coordinates are correctly generated:

```
RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> 2]
```

[image]

and the membership of particular points is also correctly recognized:

```
{5/2, 2} ∈ reg
{2, 1}   ∈ reg
{1, 5/2} ∈ reg
```

> True
>
> True
>
> False